# Python and accurate timing

Tags: python, audio, timer, pygame

I'm trying to write some code to play sounds using python.  Specifically, I have recordings of some church bells and I'm trying to play them back in particular sequences to recreate the sound of church bell ringing.  Currently I'm using pygame to handle timing and playback, like this:

```
import pygame.mixer as mx
import pygame.time as tm

mx.init()

sounds = [mx.Sound('./data/bell-{0}.wav'.format(i)) for i in range(1,9)]

def round():
    for i in range(8):
        sounds[i].play()
        tm.delay(250)            

for i in range(3):
    round()
    round()
    tm.wait(250)

mx.quit()
```

This should play something like 'ringing rounds', a regularly played scale, with each bell sounding 250ms apart and an extra gap of 250ms after each scale.

But what I get is quite uneven, even if I run python as `nice -n -19 python rounds.py`.  The variation in timing is a bit difficult to estimate, but I'd guess it's frequently well over 100ms, occasionally over 200ms.

If I import the sound files into Audacity and space them 250ms apart, I get a nice, even scale, so the problem is not just that the sound files are unevenly edited.

How can I improve this timing?  It seems to me that accurate timing should be quite important in a game library, especially when the load is quite light (as in this case).

Comment: Do you need to take into account the length of the sound file itself when calculating the delay for the next sound? Python timing should be accurate enough for this sort of thing.

Comment: I don't think so.  The unevenness is not consistent, as I would expect it to be if that were the case.

Comment: [This link](http://thepythongamebook.com/en:pygame:step010#initializing_the_mixer) states that it's better to `pre_init` the mixer *To get rid of a nasty delay between giving the play command for a sound and hearing it*.

Comment: That does the trick, although I'm curious why it makes a difference.  It seems that it is the buffer size that makes the difference; calling `pygame.mixer.pre_init` with the `buffer` argument set to 4096, the default, still gives very poor results; changing it to 2048 gives very good results (or at least good enough that my ear can't pick it).  Note also that it's not necessary to call `pre_init`; calling `pygame.mixer.init` with the buffer parameter set to 2048 has the same effect.

Comment: Would you like to write that up into an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 1, 512)` before `mx.init()`.